# download an excel file for the client (flask - python)

Tags: python-2.7

I have created an API that create an excel file and download it for the user. I need to send that file to the user. But its gets downloaded to my local server(pc). 
Here is my code..

```
wb=Workbook()
style_string = "font: bold on; borders: bottom dashed"
style = xlwt.easyxf(style_string)                
sheet1=wb.add_sheet('sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)                
sheet1.write(0,0,"token",style=style)                
sheet1.write(0,1,"translation",style=style)                
j = 0       
i = 1
for e in list(stoknwords):
  sheet1.write(i,j,e)
  i = i + 1
m = wb.save('xlwt.xls')
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(m), content_type='application/json')

#out.seek(0)
#return send_file(out, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',attachment_filename='xxl.xlsx', as_attachment=True)

#return send_file(attachment_filename="file1",as_attachment=True)               `enter code here`return json.dumps(list(stoknwords))
```

#### i have tried many return methods to send the file to the client. I am fresher so please help me..